# Paypal IPN setting for using a local virtualhost

Tags: wamp, development-environment, virtual-hosts

I have an ipn-listener class installed and working but I need some advice on how to access my Local Virtualhost address for the IPN Url setting in my Sandbox Account.

I am running numerous Virtualhosts on `127.0.0.1:80` on my Dev Setup. Their Servernames are like ‘one.localhost’, ‘two.localhost’. Therefore they are accessed on my own computer by addresses like `http://one.localhost/ipn-listener.php`.

When I try to use ‘http://one.localhost/ipn-listener.php’ in my settings I get a ‘Not properly formatted url’ warning. If I use `http://127.0.0.1/ipn-listener.php` it allows me, but of course that’s not my true uri to the Internet. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Paypal dont like odd urls, for obvious reasons, and 127.0.0.1 would point back to their own machine not yours.

You should look at setting up a URL using Dynamic DNS something like dyndns.com or noip.com. I use dyndns and they are quite good although I am not sure if they are offering free accounts anymore. Be aware, the free accounts will limit you to 1 or maybe 2 dynamic urls and dyndns is pretty cheap for up to 30 dynamic urls all pointing back to the same or different IP's.

This way you can have a vaguely normal url that will point back to your PC and PayPal will allow you to setup the listener address using that.